# Consider the complex exponential function $f \colon {\mathbb C} \to {\mathbb C}$ given by $f(z) = e^z$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Describe the image of the vertical line $\text{Re}(z) = 1$ under $f$. How would you solve such question?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: evaluate $f(1 + iy)$ with $y \in {\mathbb R}$. Simplify and use whatever you know about $e^{iy}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about the image of $z=1+i y$, $y \in \mathbb{R}$, under $w=e^z$.  Then you have

$$w = e^{1+i y} = e \cos{y} + i e \sin{y}$$